# No push notification after upgrading to iOS 8 on old device

Tags: support, status-completed, ios-app

I was eager (maybe too eager) to see what's new in iOS 8 so upgraded my iPhone 4S few days ago.

Shortly after upgrading I noticed the battery is being consumed at a crazy rate (1% every minute, I could actually see it decreasing while it was just in lock screen) so quick panic Googling took me to [this excellent article](http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/maximize-your-iphones-battery-life-ios-8-0157478/) which indeed saved my poor battery.

I took all the steps desribed in there, and apps like WhatsApp still have push notifications like before, however Stack Exchange (beta) app stopped pushing them. No push, not even the number on the app icon. When inside the app itself the inbox contains the new items properly.

Since it's only specific to SE app I'm asking here and not in https://apple.stackexchange.com/ - what can cause this? I did not change the Notifications settings:

> [image]

However this can't be a coincidence and something I changed to preserve battery caused this, so hopefully someone who is more familiar with those things can come up with an idea what I'm missing.

Comment: I believe the beta app has been having issues with push for a bit. I think it's on the serverside, but it needs a bit more investigation. It also affects iOS 7.

Comment: @Arie weird, so how come we don't have influx of reports "I don't get push notifications"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS8 comes with a new set of APIs for registering a device for push. If you were using a relatively recent version of the Beta app, which was compiled against the new SDKs, push was broken under the old methods.

This should be fixed in version **1.1.0.123**.

Would love to hear if this is working again for you after you update.

Comment: Works like a charm, can't believe it's not just me as I expected a flurry of reports!

Comment: I have version `1.1.0` according toe **Settings -> General -> Usage -> Manage Storage**. Is this the same, or are you referring to a later revision?

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon that looks like the Appstore version. In this case, the beta App is released with version 1.1.0.x. I will bump the beta version to make this less confusing.